# Vlookup in Excel userform is not working

Tags: combobox, textbox, vlookup, userform

I have a userform containing a combobox. Depending on the value of this combobox I want to fill a textbox in the same userform. I'm using the next code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Afterupdate()  
    With Me
      .TextBox4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1, 
       Sheets("Members").Range("B6:D15"), 2, 0)  
    End With  
End Sub
```

Every time I try to run the userform I get a `Runtime Error 1004 message`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly, make sure that your code is formatted and your question is precise to the point. This will help people here to concentrate on the problem statement rather than reading verbose content.

Comment: What is present in the referenced Range ?